# Camel shifts a parameter to the wrong level

Tags: java, url, parameters, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I create a camel route for connecting to my 2 ActiveMQ brokers, using failover and reconnecting to the first queue when it's up again after being down.

My route is the following:

```
    new org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder() {
        from("activemq:queue:amq.test.out?brokerURL=failover(tcp://activemq1:61616,tcp://activemq2)?randomize=false&priorityBackup=true")
...
    }
```

When camel is trying to build the route it tries to connect to Active MQ, using my broker url, but there it goes wrong. the class DefaultCamelContext has a method **normalizeEndpointUri** which converts your link to an escaped uri.

This becomes the following uri:

```
activemq://queue:amq.test.out?brokerURl=failover%3A%28tcp%3A%2F%2Factivemq1%3A616161%2Ctcp%3A%2F%2Factivemq2%3A61616%29%3Frandomize%3Dfalse&priorityBackup=true
```

The problem is at the end of the url, &priorityBack=true is not converted and will be read as part of the camel uri instead of part of the broker URL.

I tried to manually replace the **&** in my broker url by the encoded %26 but the method normalizeEndpointUri converts it back to &.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing my route to:

```
from("activemq:queue:amq.test.out?brokerURL=RAW(failover(tcp://activemq1:61616,tcp://activemq2)?randomize=false&priorityBackup=true"))
```

**RAW** takes the exact value between the brackets instead of normalizing it.

More information at https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html